# Why more numbers are less than 0 in 2's compliment

Tags: assembly, binary, bit-manipulation

In my study guide, my professor mentioned that for 2's compliment More numbers < 0 than ≥ 0. And was wondering why this is. 
Thanks!

Comment: Dunno.  For a 8-bit char: -128 to -1 has same amount of integer numbers as 0 to 127.  I think your professor may have forgotten where 0 lies in his comparison formula.

Comment: what's true is: the absolute value of the lowest number is larger then the absolute value of the highest.  (  abs(-128) > abs(127) ). (since the 0 is reducing the number of positives by one) Perhaps that's what he meant

Answer (score 3):

Either your professor is wrong, or you misunderstood what they were saying. There are the same amount of representable numbers `< 0` as there are `≥ 0`.

Every string beginning with `1` represents a distinct negative integer in two's complement. Every binary string beginning with `0` ***except the all 0 string*** represents a distinct positive integer.Thus there is one more negative integer representable than positive integers; perhaps that's what your professor meant to say.

The all `0` string represents the number `0`.

Comment: Yeah, It must be a typo I was extremely confused as to why there would be more negative numbers in 2's compliment when you have to change the sign of it to do it. Thanks so much for reaffirming my thoughts!